# Crear buffer relleno con ceros en OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

Tengo este multikernel en OpenCL para dispositivos Intel FPGA que se comunica mediante canales:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_intel_channels : enable
channel int chan_in __attribute__((depth(0)));
channel int chan_out __attribute__((depth(0)));

// Kernel que padea con ceros la señal de entrada 
// adaptándola a las nuevas dimensiones
__attribute__((max_global_work_dim(0)))
__kernel void reader(global int *data_out, 
                     int rows, int cols,
                     int pad) 
{
    int index, i, j = 0;
    int shift = pad * cols; // Desplazamiento de filas
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            // Se calcula el índice donde insertar el valor
            index = pad * (j + i * shift); 
            // Se lee el valor y se inserta
            data_out[index] = read_channel_intel(chan_out); 
        }
    }
}

// Kernel que envía los valores ya calculados
__attribute__((max_global_work_dim(0)))
__kernel void writer(global int *data_in, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        write_channel_intel(chan_in, data_in[i]);
    }
}

// Interfaz entre kernels
__attribute__((max_global_work_dim(0)))
__attribute__((autorun))
__kernel void plusOne() 
{
    while(1) {
        int input = read_channel_intel(chan_in);
        write_channel_intel(chan_out, input);
    }
}
```

El kernel `writer` se encarga de escribir en el canal que recibe `reader` para leer el valor e introducirlo en el índice adecuado del buffer de salida, `data_out`, teniendo en cuenta el factor de escala. El problema es que alguna posiciones del vector de salida no valen cero, si no valores aleatorios que además, se repiten. Por ejemplo, para una matriz de 2x2 que aplanada sería un vector de 4 posiciones, y un factor de escala de dos (es decir, transformo la matriz de 2x2 en una de 4x4) obtengo un resultado correcto, que sería el siguiente:

```
Input data:
1 2 3 4

Output data:
1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 4 0 0 0 0 0
```

Sin embargo, al aplicar un factor de escala de 3 (esto me devuelve una matriz de 6x6) el vector de salida que obtengo es:

```
Input data:
1 2 3 4

Output data:
1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 9939176 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Donde se aprecia el valor aleatorio `9939176`. 
En el programa host he creado los buffers de la siguiente manera:

```
// Buffer de salida de la FPGA (memoria global) con las dimensiones 
// ya re-escaladas por el factor
output_buf = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
             array_size * sizeof(unsigned int), NULL, &status);

// Array de salida en el host (no es del tipo ClBuffer)
unsigned int *output = (unsigned int *)malloc(array_size*sizeof(int));

// Para asegurarme de que el array del host vale todo ceros y 
// que el valor aleatorio se copia del dispitivo (FPGA) al host, 
// recorro el array poniendo todas sus posiciones a cero.
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    output[i] = 0;
}

// Finalemnte, relleno el array de salida con los valores obtenidos 
// del buffer de salida del dispositivo

status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(fpga_to_host_queue, output_buf, 
         CL_FALSE, 0, array_size*sizeof(unsigned int), 
         output, 1, &out_kernel_event, &finish_event);
```

Tras realizar estas pruebas está claro que ese valor aleatorio lo genera el dispositivo. ¿Es posible crear un buffer mediante `clCreateBuffer` de ceros? ¿He de asignar valores a todas las posiciones del array?

Comment: En [tag:c++] no se usa `malloc`, se usa `new`.

Comment: Hola! gracias por la rápida respuesta. Es el ejemplo que proporciona Intel, con las modificaciones que le he hecho. Voy a probar con new. Pero, como digo, creo que el problema es del dispositivo, puesto que el array del host donde vuelvo el buffer si que lo seteo con ceros. Eso sería correcto, no?

Comment: Seguramente intel está proporcionando un ejemplo para [tag:c], no para [tag:c++].

Comment: Gracias @4lrdyD He intentando añadir la etiqueta OpenCL pero no me dejaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es crear el buffer de salida y el array de salida inicializado con ceros, para después escribir en el buffer de salida el array de salida del host, tal que así:

```
// Se crea el array de salida
unsigned int *output = new unsigned int[array_size];

// Se rellena con ceros el array de salida 
// Buscar la forma mas eficiente posible
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    output[i] = 0;
}

// Se crea el buffer de salida para la FPGA
output_buf = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
             array_size * sizeof(unsigned int), 
             NULL, &status);
if(status != CL_SUCCESS) printf( "Failed to create output_buf\n");

cl_event write_event;
cl_event finish_event;

// Se escribe en el buffer de salida el array con ceros
status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(host_to_fpga_queue, output_buf, CL_FALSE, 0, 
         array_size * sizeof(unsigned int), output, 0, NULL, &write_event);
if(status!=CL_SUCCESS) printf("Failed to transfer input\n");
```

Al ejecutar para una matriz de entrada de 3x3 y un factor de 2, la salida obtenida es:

```
Input data:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

Output data:
1 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```